# How do I share state between routes in React-Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I've seen a few questions similar to this on SO but none that quite matched my needs. I'm using React and Material-UI to make a dashboard. I'm using Material-UI's mini variant drawer as a sidebar, with links that should display routes when clicked. The sidebar can be opened by clicking a button, which updates a state variable and adjusts the CSS className of the sidebar. This causes the sidebar/drawer to "slide" open.

If I click a link on the sidebar, I can easily display a desired route. However, I can't get the route to also "slide" to the side when the sidebar/drawer opens. It will probably be easier to understand by looking at the code, so I've included a link to a codesandbox below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/appbar-with-react-router-bkogj?file=/src/App.js

I basically copy and pasted everything from the Material-UI website (using v4 I believe), then added the route myself. Would appreciate any feedback on how to solve this issue.

Comment: did you look at the mui Persistent drawer? https://mui.com/components/drawers/
that should actually give you everything you need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I think the `MiniDrawer` component needs to render the content since it necessarily is aware of the space the appbar and drawer components occupy.

### MiniDrawer

Take and render a `children` prop.

```
export default function MiniDrawer({ children }) {
  ...

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        ...
      >
        ...
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        ...
      >
        ...
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>{children}</main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### App

Render the `Outlet` as a child component.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar>
        <Outlet />
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### RejectTable

Remove the excess margin so it fills the content area the parent component allows.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    height: "100%",
    // marginLeft: "4em" // <-- remove
  }
}));
```

[image: Edit how-do-i-share-state-between-routes-in-react-router]